# Calling Alchemy API using ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, rest, alchemyapi

I am trying to use ajax to call the Alchemy REST API, but I am getting an injector error which I have mentioned below. The following is the code in my HTML file. Looking for suggestions to solve the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" ></meta>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

Alchemy trial
<span id="yammer-login"></span>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/url/URLGetRankedKeywords',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'url=http://yurishelke.weebly.com&apikey=apikey&maxRetrieve=1', // or $('#myform').serializeArray()
        success: function(keyword) { 
            //document.getElementById('yammer-login').innerHTML = keyword;
            console.dir(keyword);
            alert('PUT completed');  
        }

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error in the console :-

```
[21:39:07.317] Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/unpr?p0=AngularIssuesProvider%20%3C-%20AngularIssues
L/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:6
Xb/l.$injector<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:32
c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:29
Xb/r.$injector<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:32
c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:29
d@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js:30
Xb/f/<.instantiate@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be that AlchemyAPI returns multiple CORS headers like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Which is actually interpreted in the browser like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, *
```

Which is invalid per the standard, and improperly interpreted by the browser.

That aside, you probably shouldn't be hitting AlchemyAPI directly.  Instead, you should be using a web server to proxy the API calls, and hitting that server with AJAX.  By putting the AJAX call to the API client-side, you're giving out your key to any person or device that uses it, and now, you've given it to anyone that views this question on Stack Exchange.